# Move cursor in insert mode of Vim in vimrc file

Tags: vim

1. In `.vimrc` how to use following key functions in `insert mode`

   end, home, arrow keys, numerical keys
2. When I moved from `normal mode` to `insert mode`using `i` command, the cursor moves 1 character backward. How to stop it? (using a `.vimrc` command or any other way)

Comment: end, home, arrow keys and numerical keys should work out of the box in insert mode. How exactly are you using vim that they seem not to work?

Comment: I experienced the behaviour about arrow keys not working in insert mode with some installations of vim on Ubuntu (maybe it was the `vim-tiny` package). Make sure your system is running a complete version of `vim`.

Comment: They works fine in insert mode. But what I wanted is a `command` which is equivalent to the arrow keys, home and end to write a `inoremap` in insert mode.

Comment: It may be a good idea to post this in a second question.

Comment: When asking two unrelated questions you should post them as separate questions.

Comment: Why exactly do you need to be able to use the end,home keys etc. in insert mode in your `.vimrc` instead of just doing the movements that you need in your `.vimrc` in normal mode and then changing to insert mode when you actually need it?

Answer (score 6):

To your second question: You can use <kbd>a</kbd> to switch to insert mode instead of <kbd>i</kbd>.

This will place the cursor in insert mode behind the previously highlighted character instead of before it like <kbd>i</kbd> does.

Answer (score 2):

1. Special keys are usually a sequence of escape codes.  Instead of mapping ugly escape codes that you'll never understand when you look at it again, how about mapping the normal mode equivalent?  `<C-o>` allows you to run a single command in normal mode and return to insert mode.

   For example, the following map will make X in insert mode move one character to the right and remain in insert mode.

   ```
    inoremap X <C-o>l
   ```
2. You can not prevent the cursor from "moving to the left" when exiting insert mode.  You can think of it as the cursor always rests on a character.  If the cursor didn't "move" then it wouldn't be resting on a character at the end of a line.  As FlyingFoX already pointed out, you can use <kbd>a</kbd> instead of <kbd>i</kbd> to enter insert mode and this "move" won't affect you.

Comment: with the mapping in your answer, how can you type `SEX`?

Comment: I just used `X` as an example.  I have no idea what he actually wants to map.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried, the End, Home, Arrows works without special setting. If you started vim in terminal, for some terminal you need to set `term` to a proper value. It could be different.  If you are using `vim`, be sure that you have `set nocompatible` However I would suggest you that forget the arrows/home/end keys, move in this way:

```
<esc>A   (Insert End)
<esc>I or gI (Insert Home)
<Esc>hjkl (arrows)
```

Enter Insert mode only if you really want to insert text otherwise stay in normal mode. you can also consider to press `<C-o>`

Q2, the `i` was designed like that in vim. There are different ways to enter insert mode. `i a s c I A o O ...` read the help of those commands, try them by yourself, and think about it, you will find out, they will make your daily editing productive.

Comment: Yes Ctrl + ox - Temporarily enter normal mode to issue one normal-mode command x , which could be a navigation. Great tip i looked for this.

Answer (score 2):

For mappings with special keys in insert mode, just use the special key notation as normal. For example:

```
inoremap <F5> <Left><Left>hello
nnoremap <F5> a<Left><Left>hello<Esc>
```